# How can I determine which namespaces a PID is in from kernel space?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I am trying to write an eBPF program to log every call of a particular syscall from containers running on the system. I am using [bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc) and can retrieve the PID using `bpf_get_current_pid_tgid()`.

From userspace I could examine the proc filesystem to determine if the process's namespaces differ from the root namespaces to guess whether it's a container process or not, but I do not know how do you do this from kernel space?

Comment: Starting Linux 4.8, you can use the `bpf_get_current_task` helper to retrieve `struct task_struct`. [`bpf_get_current_task()->nsproxy`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.14/source/include/linux/sched.h#L778) gives you the [namespaces](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.14/source/include/linux/nsproxy.h#L31) of the current process. What are you looking for exactly? The PID inside the container?

Comment: Awesome, I'll check that out - well I want to be able to determine/guess within an eBPF program whether a process is running inside a container or not and if so I want to stream any interactive shell sessions back to some central place for audit purposes. This could allow administrators play back any potentially malicious sessions

Comment: It's very much a work in progress but I'm trying to understand what is possible with eBPF as it seems like such a powerful tool

Comment: I'll write a proper answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the (Linux 4.8+ only) `bpf_get_current_task` helper to retrieve the `struct task_struct` of the current process. Then the PID as seen by processes inside the container is in `t->nsproxy->pid_ns_for_children->last_pid`.

The following shows this in action when tracing `execve` syscalls (you can use `top` inside the container to check that the upid is correct):

```python
from bcc import BPF
BPF(text="""
#include <linux/pid_namespace.h>
int kprobe__sys_execve(void *ctx) {
    u32 pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    struct task_struct *t = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
    u32 upid = t->nsproxy->pid_ns_for_children->last_pid;
    bpf_trace_printk("pid=%d; upid=%d!\\n", pid, upid);
    return 0;
}
""").trace_print()
```

---

The following diff (based of [a44d26ed3](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/a44d26ed3e5e40eaad8e69d630562fb389266bee/tools/execsnoop.py)) extends bcc's `execsnoop.py` to retrieve the upid:

```
diff --git a/tools/execsnoop.py b/tools/execsnoop.py
index 5711fd1..2134f69 100755
--- a/tools/execsnoop.py
+++ b/tools/execsnoop.py
@@ -53,6 +53,7 @@ bpf_text = """
 #include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
 #include <linux/sched.h>
 #include <linux/fs.h>
+#include <linux/pid_namespace.h>

 #define ARGSIZE  128

@@ -63,6 +64,7 @@ enum event_type {

 struct data_t {
     u32 pid;  // PID as in the userspace term (i.e. task->tgid in kernel)
+    u32 upid;
     char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];
     enum event_type type;
     char argv[ARGSIZE];
@@ -119,6 +121,8 @@ int kretprobe__sys_execve(struct pt_regs *ctx)
 {
     struct data_t data = {};
     data.pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
+    struct task_struct *t = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
+    data.upid = t->nsproxy->pid_ns_for_children->last_pid;
     bpf_get_current_comm(&data.comm, sizeof(data.comm));
     data.type = EVENT_RET;
     data.retval = PT_REGS_RC(ctx);
@@ -134,7 +138,7 @@ b = BPF(text=bpf_text.replace("MAXARG", args.max_args))
 # header
 if args.timestamp:
     print("%-8s" % ("TIME(s)"), end="")
-print("%-16s %-6s %-6s %3s %s" % ("PCOMM", "PID", "PPID", "RET", "ARGS"))
+print("%-16s %-6s %-6s %-6s %3s %s" % ("PCOMM", "PID", "UPID", "PPID", "RET", "ARGS"))

 TASK_COMM_LEN = 16      # linux/sched.h
 ARGSIZE = 128           # should match #define in C above
@@ -142,6 +146,7 @@ ARGSIZE = 128           # should match #define in C above
 class Data(ct.Structure):
     _fields_ = [
         ("pid", ct.c_uint),
+        ("upid", ct.c_uint),
         ("comm", ct.c_char * TASK_COMM_LEN),
         ("type", ct.c_int),
         ("argv", ct.c_char * ARGSIZE),
@@ -189,8 +194,8 @@ def print_event(cpu, data, size):
             if args.timestamp:
                 print("%-8.3f" % (time.time() - start_ts), end="")
             ppid = get_ppid(event.pid)
-            print("%-16s %-6s %-6s %3s %s" % (event.comm.decode(), event.pid,
-                    ppid if ppid > 0 else "?", event.retval,
+            print("%-16s %-6s %-6s %-6s %3s %s" % (event.comm.decode(), event.pid,
+                    event.upid, ppid if ppid > 0 else "?", event.retval,
                     b' '.join(argv[event.pid]).decode()))
         try:
             del(argv[event.pid])
```

Comment: That's really cool, thanks - I tried adapting this to mount namespaces but I'm not getting the expected result. I'm printing the following value: `t->nsproxy->mnt_ns->ns.inum` but I always get the value 0, regardless of whether I'm execing in a container or not

Comment: This is probably due to the randomized `task_struct` in kernel 4.13 as answered in your GitHub issue. I posted a comment in your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392152/how-can-i-use-ebpf-to-trace-container-exec-sessions); did you get a chance to look into it?

Comment: Thank you, yeah I switched to 4.11 and everything is working nicely :) I replied with a few details of what I've got working

Comment: Since 4.15, this no longer works as the `last_pid` field was replaced.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/95846ecf9dac